# Difference between using App::environment() vs app()->environment() vs config('app.env')

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, config, laravel-9

What's the difference between using `App::environment()` vs `app()->environment()` vs `config('app.env')` for checking environment? I assume the first two are the exact same thing, but what about those vs using `config('app.env')`?

What I can see the first two returns the whole service container instance, so is that worse for performance, but more secure or something? I'm reading that people recommend only using `config()` for your own config variables and for any other config variable that isn't the env one. Trying to figure out the reasoning.

Thanks!

Comment: *What I can see the first two returns the whole service container instance* - Can you clarify this? It should be returning a boolean? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#determining-the-current-environment

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they will do the same thing. `App::` vs `app()` is just choosing whether to use the Facade or the helper function, but both will use the same code underneath. These are probably considered preferable since they are a more intuitive API for accessing the environment (they read clearer as well)

Comment: In the end, both `App::environment()` and `app()->environment()` **defer to** `config('app.env')`. Which in turn becomes `app('config')->get('app.env')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App::environment()` and `app()->environment()` are the exact same thing. The `App` facade and the `app()` helper function are both just shortcuts to access your application container.

In a web context (hitting your page from a browser), the `App::environment()` method and the `config('app.env')` function will return the same value.

In a cli context (artisan command, queued job, etc), the `App::environment()` method and the `config('app.env')` function could return different values. If the command being run is executed with the `--env` argument (ex: `--env=testing`), then the `App::environment()` method will return the actual detected environment ("testing"), whereas the `config('app.env')` function will continue to return the environment defined in your config file.

Two extra things to consider:

1. The `environment()` method is part of the public api. This means the only potential for breaking changes is on major releases. The `app.env` config value is not part of the public api. Laravel could change that at any point if they wanted to, even on a minor release. I doubt they ever would, but they've made no public promises.
2. The `environment()` method takes optional parameters to add a little syntactic sugar for testing your current environment. If you pass parameters, the method will return a boolean if you're in any of the supplied environments, instead of returning a string with the name of the current environment. The parameters are also treated as regex searches:

   ```
   $isTesting = App::environment('test', 'testing', 'testarossa')
   // or
   $isTesting = App::environment('test*')
   ```

   (the "*" is replaced with ".*" before the regex is run)

Answer (score 2):

**App::environment()**
uses a Facade to get the environment, a facade of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.

**app()**
uses a helper function to return the `\Illuminate\Container\Container::getInstance()`. `environment()` in a method of this Container instance.

**resolve()**
is an alias for `app()` but expects a parameter e.g. `resolve('config')` or `resolve(Application::class)`.

**app()->make(Application::class)**
Uses the Container to resolve the Application. This is equal to `app(Application::class)`.

**Config::get('app.env')**
uses the Facade of `\Illuminate\Config\Repository`.

**config('app.env')**
uses a helper function to call `app()` to resolve the Config. You should **only** use `env()` when you are working in a config file located in `config/`.

**public function __construct(Config $config)**
uses dependency injection to resolve the Config.

### Answer

When bootstrapping the Application, [the config variables are loaded](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php) in this application using the Config.

So the Container uses Config to load the variables. Both are singletons, so calling them does not really affect the performance.

Which solution you choose sometimes depends on the use-case and mostly on preference.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `environment()` function in `Application` returns `$this['env']`. However, I can't see where this is set. Have you found it by any chance?

Comment: I believe that is in the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It calls the `Application`'s `detectEnvironment()` method which in turn sets it.

Comment: Based on this, I'd say the best way to call the environment is using `Config::get('app.env')`. It's less steps.

Comment: Some people prefer helper functions, others only want to use dependency injection (like me :P). And there are the people that are a huge fan of facades.

Comment: I prefer the helper, but I've heard people saying the facades can provide nice IDE integrations

Comment: @IGP i can see that, but when you want to check more than one value the `app()->environment([’local’, ’staging’])` way seems nicer!